# Get specific part of json object which has a certain value

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm trying to get a specific part of Json, but couldn't figure out how.

My json looks like:

```
[
    {
        "ResourceId":"1",
        "ResourceText":"Hello",
        "LanguageId":"1"
    },
    {
        "ResourceId":"2",
        "ResourceText":"World",
        "LanguageId":"1"
    }
    .
    .
    .
]
```

So for example I want the part (changes according to pResourceId parameter, so what I'm trying to get changes everytime)

```
    {
        "ResourceId":"1",
        "ResourceText":"Hello",
        "LanguageId":"1"
    }
```

But I couldn't get it. What I tried so far:

```
JObject data = JObject.Parse(jsonStringResources);
return data.Values().Where(x => x.Contains("ResourceId\" : \"" +pResourceId +"\"")  ) as clsResource;
```

Comment: If your JSON is really well structured like that, any reason you don't want to just convert to a `List<T>` for some class with `ResourceId`, `ResourceText` and `LanguageId` properties? It would also help if you'd provide a short but *complete* example demonstrating the problem - the JSON you've provided is for an array, not an object, which makes it harder to test without messing with things.

Comment: @JonSkeet, let's say I have approx. 100.000 resources like the above one, if I deserialize it everytime and get what i want with linq, would the memory consumption be huge? if so, I'd want to use the possible answer this question get. if not, I can use what you suggested. But, I really couldn't find anything in this regard.

Comment: I suspect it may well be *smaller* than deserializing it all as a `JArray`/`JObject`.

Comment: hmm than I'll use that, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make a model for the format of your JSON:

```
class Model
{
    public string ResourceId { get; set; }
    public string ResourceText { get; set; }
    public string LanguageId { get; set; }
}
```

And then you can do:

```
var models = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Model>>(jsonStringResources);
var matchingModel = models.Where(model => model.ResourceId == pResourceId).ToList().FirstOrDefault();

return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(matchingModel);
```

We deserialize the JSON into a list of our models. We then get the model where the `ResourceId` matches the `pResourceId`. Finally, we serialize the model again to get the JSON string.

When `pResourceId == 1`, the result is:

```
{
  "ResourceId": "1",
  "ResourceText": "Hello",
  "LanguageId": "1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your json looks like that, you can deserialize it into object which would be:

```
public class JsonTestModel
{
    public JsonTestModel()
    {

    }
    public int ResourceId { get; set; }
    public string ResourceText { get; set; }
    public int LanguageId { get; set; }

}
```

and then you could search for it like this:

```
List<JsonTestModel> theListWithModels = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JsonTestModel>>(theJsonString);

var extractedModels = theListWithModels.Where(m => m.ResourceId == pResourceId);
```