# Extract part of the JSON content (property) and convert to c# object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net

How to get part of json content and convert to c# object. API returning below JSON content. from that I need to get "ContentItems" part and convert to C# object. I already created the "ContentItems" Class.

I am using `Newtonsoft.Json`. It is hard to get to the part of it.

```
{
    "SubmissionId": 69,
    "SubmissionKey": "a1c78c25-b885-4ec0-8032-040fca6b447e",
    "CreatedUserId": 4,
    "ResourceType": "Article",
    "Files": [
       {
        "SubmissionFileId": 149,
        "FileName": "ARMA-81-0475.xml",
         "ContentItems": [
                {
                "ContentItemId": 132,
                "ContentKey": "8f8b2f74-ba29-4b7d-a44f-8d119dc2aab7",
                "SubmissionFile": null,                    
                }
           ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**ContentItems.cs**

```
public class ContentItems
{
    public int ContentItemId { get; set; }
    public string ContentKey { get; set; }
    public string SubmissionFile { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get specific part of json object which has a certain value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31856828/get-specific-part-of-json-object-which-has-a-certain-value)

Comment: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSONFragments.htm

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonContent);
var item = obj.Files[0].ContentItems[0].ToObject<ContentItems>();
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can extract just `ContentItems` from your JSON using JSONPath

```
var recs = JObject.Parse("*** JSON Text ***").SelectTokens("$..Files[*].ContentItems[*]")
    .Select(j => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ContentItems>(j.ToString()));

foreach (var rec in recs)
    Console.WriteLine(rec.ContentItemId);
```